# Excel VBA Macro to remove a specific duplicate character and leave one instance each time it finds it in a string

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Windows 10
Microsoft Excel 2019

I have a Excel worksheet with multiple strings in each cell of Column A

The strings are formatted like this:

```
Some Text;;;;;;More text;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Even more text;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Yet More;;And more text;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;And More
```

I need to be able to remove the duplicate `;` and leave only one instance at each place the duplicates appear like this:

```
Some Text;More text;Even more text;Yet More;And more text;And More
```

This needs to be something I can repeat when ever I need to so that's why I am thinking a macro or VBA would be best.

I am unable to find way within Excel that will do this and leave only one instance of the ";" character.

In VBA I can remove all duplicates of any characters using

```
Public Sub RemoveDupeChars2()
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Application.Selection
    cell.Value = RemoveDupeChars(cell.Value)
  Next
End Sub
```

But this does not allow me to specify a specific character to remove the duplicates of or to then leave one instance where ever in the string it finds them.

Comment: Post the code of `RemoveDupeChars` Sub or Function. You have only posted for `RemoveDupeChars2`.

Comment: '''RemoveDupeChars2''' is just the macro name and the code is underneath that in my post. Are you viewing this on a mobile device?

Comment: Your code is incomplete!!!

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry about that slip up.

Answer (score 0):

The RemoveDupeChars() function works very well. It does not fulfill your task, because [**it is intended for something completely different**](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/remove-duplicates-within-cell-excel/#:%7E:text=User%2Ddefined%20function%20to%20delete%20repeated%20characters). You need the removeSpecificDupeChars() function:

```
Function removeSpecificDupeChars(sourceText As String, sChar As String)  As String
Dim aTemp As Variant 
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    aTemp = Split(sourceText, sChar)
    j = LBound(aTemp)
    For i = LBound(aTemp) + 1 To UBound(aTemp)
        If aTemp(i) <> "" Then
            j = j + 1
            aTemp(j) = aTemp(i)
        EndIf
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve aTemp(j)
    removeSpecificDupeChars = Join(aTemp, sChar)
End Function
```

The procedure you showed in your question should be modified:

```
Public Sub RemoveDupeChars3()
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Application.Selection
    cell.Value = removeSpecificDupeChars(cell.Value, ";")
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding my clumsy post. Your code works perfectly on 30 - 40 cells A1 - A40 but anything more than that then Excel shows (Not Responding) and I have close the program?

Answer (score 0):

The following code, using Regular Expressions, processed over a 1000 lines in a fraction of a second.

You will need to change the range reference as needed. You could use `Selection` if you must.

Note that working in VBA arrays is much faster than repeatedly accessing the worksheet itself.

```
Option Explicit
Sub deDupSemiColons()
    Dim rg As Range, v, I As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim RE As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WS

'Range is in column A starting at A1
    Set rg = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    v = rg
End With

With RE
    .Pattern = ";+"
    .Global = True
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        v(I, 1) = RE.Replace(v(I, 1), ";")
    Next I
    
End With

rg.Value = v
End Sub
```